# I can't pull images from firebase_storage in my Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase

I decided to pull some of my image files from firebase storage in my Flutter application because the total size of the images is about 25gb. when I want to pull the images, I get some kind of 'firebase cannot be called' warning, how do I solve this problem?

If you can't get an idea about the code, here's a hint: I'm making an application that displays images with a page-turning animation. so the firebase operation must be compatible with this.

Warning Text

```
I/flutter ( 6311): Error getting image URL: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
I/chatty  ( 6311): uid=10148(com.example.libsy_app) 1.ui identical 2 lines
I/flutter ( 6311): Error getting image URL: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

This my code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_flip/page_flip.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(AChristmasCarol());
}

final _controller = GlobalKey<PageFlipWidgetState>();

class AChristmasCarol extends StatefulWidget {
  const AChristmasCarol({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AChristmasCarol> createState() => _AChristmasCarolState();
}

class _AChristmasCarolState extends State<AChristmasCarol> {
  final _controller = GlobalKey<PageFlipWidgetState>();

  // sharedPreferences to store lastLeftOverPage Index
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // last left over page index
  int lastLeftOverPageIndex = 0;

  // SharedPreference key to retrieve the  value of lastLeftOverPageIndex
  String lastLeftOverPageNoPrefKey = "_lastLeftOverPageNoPrefKey";

  final List<String> imagesPath = [
    '/books/A Christmas Carol/page 1.png',
    '/books/A Christmas Carol/page 2.png',
    '/books/A Christmas Carol/page 3.png',
    '/books/A Christmas Carol/page 4.png',
  ];

  late List<String> downloadUrls;

  Widget _buildDemoPage(String imageUrl) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getImageUrl(imageUrl),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error fetching image'));
        }
        return Scaffold(
          body: Image.network(
            snapshot.data!,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<String?> _getImageUrl(String imageUrl) async {
    try {
      final url = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(imageUrl)
          .getDownloadURL();
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting image URL: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // restore the previous lastLeftOverPageIndex;
    _restoreLeftOverPage();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _restoreLeftOverPage() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await _prefs;
    lastLeftOverPageIndex =
        pref.getInt(lastLeftOverPageNoPrefKey)?.toInt() ?? 0;
    // navigate the book page index to lastLeftOverPageIndex
    _controller.currentState?.goToPage(lastLeftOverPageIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageFlipWidget(
        key: _controller,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        initialIndex: lastLeftOverPageIndex,
        lastPage: Container(
            color: Colors.white, child: const Center(child: Text('The End!'))),
        children: [
          for (var imagePath in imagesPath) _buildDemoPage(imagePath),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.looks_one_outlined),
        onPressed: () {
          _controller.currentState?.goToPage(1);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
    // before disposing the widget save the current page no
    var currentPageNo = _controller.currentState?.pageNumber.toInt() ?? 0;
    saveLastLeftOverPagePref(currentPageNo);
  }

  Future<void> saveLastLeftOverPagePref(int lastPage) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await _prefs;
    pref.setInt(lastLeftOverPageNoPrefKey, lastPage);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any configuration data to `Firebase.initializeApp()`, which is different from the code in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#initialize-firebase. Where does your code get its configuration from?

Comment: Actually, I configure it via main.dart, but I added it for trial and error purposes (I think I forgot to delete it from the code when opening the question title).  But whether I delete it from the code or not, I continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _buildDemoPage(String imageUrl) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: Firebase.initializeApp().then((_) => _getImageUrl(imageUrl)),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null) {
        return Center(child: Text('Error fetching image'));
      }
      return Scaffold(
        body: Image.network(
          snapshot.data!,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

i think u should try this : modify your _buildDemoPage method

Comment: Can you expand on why this is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not passing the `FirebaseOptions` (basically the config object) to the initializer method. Please follow the steps to configure your Firebase project and to solve this issue.

First, run the following command to enable FlutterFire CLI tool and setup your Firebase project to work with your Flutter App

```bash
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

```bash
flutterfire configure
```

Note that you'll need Firebase CLI for the same. If you haven't installed Firebase CLI, you need to install it first. [Follow the documentation here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)

Once you complete `flutterfire configure` command execution, import the generated `firebase_options.dart` file into your `main.dart`.

```dart
import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

After that, replace the following line in your `main` method:

```dart
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

With this:

```dart
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

You're good to go! Hope this helps!

Comment: I get this kind of error in consol, please help me :(                                                                       
                                                                                                                 
E/StorageException( 5585): {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 5585): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}

Comment: @MuhammedHalilDemirci, I'm not sure unless you show me more details like stack trace. If I'm correct, it sounds like a your Firebase Storage's security rule is declining access to the images. Double check that on the firebase console. If that's not the problem, kindly share more details.

Comment: I/flutter ( 4890): Error getting image URL: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.
E/StorageUtil( 4890): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/StorageUtil( 4890): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

Comment: yes exactly as you said I can't get access to view the pictures in the application. i tried to make some authorisations through the console firebase but it didn't work. i am sending you the full version of the output.

Comment: Hello thank you for everything !!! I solved my problem. Result: I change stroge rules and i using physical device.